# Sql Server 2008 partition table based on insert date

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, bulkinsert, partitioning

My question is about table partitioning in SQL Server 2008.

I have a program that loads data into a table every 10 mins or so. Approx 40 million rows per day.

The data is bcp'ed into the table and needs to be able to be loaded very quickly.

I would like to partition this table based on the date the data is inserted into the table. Each partition would contain the data loaded in one particular day.

The table should hold the last 50 days of data, so every night I need to drop any partitions older than 50 days.

I would like to have a process that aggregates data loaded into the current partition every hour into some aggregation tables. The summary will only ever run on the latest partition (since all other partitions will already be summarised) so it is important it is partitioned on insert_date.

Generally when querying the data, the insert date is specified (or multiple insert dates). The detailed data is queried by drilling down from the summarised data and as this is summarised based on insert date, the insert date is always specified when querying the detailed data in the partitioned table.

Can I create a default column in the table "Insert_date" that gets a value of Getdate() and then partition on this somehow?

OR

I can create a column in the table "insert_date" and put a hard coded value of today's date.

What would the partition function look like?

Would seperate tables and a partitioned view be better suited?

Comment: Since no-one else was brave enough, I'll comment. Your partition plan sounds possible but will have a high management overhead, making sure Partitions are created in time and cleaning out (deleting?) old ones. I'm not sure how the db will react when the Partition column is taking a default value; it may be necessary to specify it in the insert statement. One question: why do you want to partition it? Is it for space or performance reasons?

Comment: Hi Salvador. Thanks for your reply. A bit of both. It is a very large amount of data and it needs to hold a rolling 60 days. So each day we need to delete a days worth of data. Also there is a lot of aggregation that runs on only the most current partition. When querying this data it is usually queried for only a distinct partition. Thanks for your comments, much appreciated!

Comment: What you are describing is exactly what partitioning strategies were designed to do; here's a great tutorial on it, but I think this question should be closed because it's broad.  http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/01/sql-server-table-partitioning-tutorial-videos-and-scripts/

Answer (score 0):

I have tried both, and even though I think partition tables are cooler. But after trying to teach how to maintain the code afterwards it just wasten't justified. In that scenario we used a hard coded field date field that was in the insert statement.

Now I use different tables ( 31 days / 31 tables ) + aggrigation table and there is an ugly union all query that joins togeather the monthly data. 
Advantage. Super timple sql, and simple c# code for bcp and nobody has complained about complexity.

But if you have the infrastructure and a gaggle of .net / sql gurus I would choose the partitioning strategy.